# Kindle Fire USB Debugging Mode

Tags: android, kindle-fire

I am porting android apps to Kindle Fire in eclipse. the problem is that i did not know how to on/off the USB debugging mode of Kindle Fire??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a simple how to

[debug mode](http://answers.groovypost.com/questions/668/how-do-i-enable-usb-debugging-on-kindle-fire)

Comment: As it happened. (site is unreachable for me ATM)

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to add the Fire's device ID to your `android_usb.ini` file so that the Google ADB drivers will find it. You can do this from the command line very easily with:

```
echo 0x1949 >> "%USERPROFILE%\.android\adb_usb.ini
```

Then restart adb

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Comment: thanks for the help.. will this activity on/off the Kindle fire USB ??

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I enable USB Debugging on Kindle Devices

From the Kindle Fire, open “Settings“.

Do one of the following depending on your device:

Original Kindle Fire – No action needed. ADB is enabled by default.

Kindle Fire HD – Select "Security".

HDX and Newer Models – Tap “Device” or "Device Options", then tap “Serial Number” 7 times until “Developer Options” is unlocked.

Choose “Developer Options“.
Set “Enable ADB” to “On“ and allow USB debugging.

You will now be able to see your device in the device list while trying to run your application . You can go to the same option to switch off USB debugging.

I didn't have to download any separate drivers for Kindle Devices but I always ensure that my Android SDK tools and platforms are kept upto date .

Answer (score 1):

### Enable Developer Options

Go to Settings > Device Options and look for a Developer Options menu. If it's not there, do the following:

- Go to **Settings > Device Options > About Fire Tablet**.
- Tap your **Serial Number** seven times.
- Return to **Device Options**. A    new menu appears called "Developer
  Options."

Tap **Developer options**. (2013 models might call this option "Security.")
Set **Developer options** and **USB debugging** to ON.
If you have a Kindle Fire 1st Generation, ADB is enabled by default.

For more info visit [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tablets/connecting-adb-to-device.html)